# The shortest distance of points of on $y^2 =2x+10$ from the origin of the coordinates .

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The shortest distance of points of on $y^2 =2x+10$ from the origin of the coordinates .(W**ithout derivative use** )

I can use the derivative to solve the question but Without derivatives I can not . please help me !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: The distance is given by $$d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+2x+10},$$
and the radicand can be written as $$x^2+2x+10=x^2+2x+1-1+10=(x+1)^2+9.$$

Answer (score 1):

The shortest distance is obtained when the circle $x^2+y^2=d^2$ is tangent to the parabola $y^2=2x+10$.

*Because if $d$ is smaller, there is no intersection and if $d$ is greater there are multiple intersections meaning the curves cross each other and that contradicts the fact the $d$ is the minimal distance to origin.*

Thus we search for intersections between the two curves ($d>0$)

$\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2=d^2\\
y^2=2x+10\end{cases}\implies x^2+2x+10-d^2=0$

This is a tangency point for $\Delta=0$ (*same reason than explained before, it has to be a double root*).

$\iff 4-4(10-d^2)=4(d^2-9)=0\iff d=3$

In fact the tangency condition is Lagrange multipliers in disguise...